# How to turn arrays to classes like fullphp

Tags: php, fuelphp

I'am using the fullPHP Library and I do not understand some sources.

The library has a config-class witch will be called like

```
Config::load('test.php', true);
```

the test.php looks like this:

```
<?php

return array(
  'base_url'  => null,
  'profiling_paths' => array(
      'APPPATH' => 'APPPATH',
      'COREPATH' => 'COREPATH',
      'PKGPATH' => 'PKGPATH'
  )
);
```

In the class itself the test.php is interpreted like an array not like a string. How does it works?

You will find the class here:
https://github.com/fuel/core/blob/1.9/develop/classes/config.php

Comment: Read again what [method](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uqJNhuCqW-Y) does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: the `Config::load('test.php', true)` method call loads the content of the `test.php` file (`array`) and stores it in the `Config` class `static::$items` property array. When you call `Config::get('key')` the value recieves from that `static::$items` property array by 'key' (`static::$items['key']`) and returns by the method.

If you want just to use arrays in the "object-oriented style", you can use the ArrayIterator class from the SPL library.

```
$arrayObject = new ArrayIterator([]);
```

See the [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayiterator.php).